# What does 'classic' profession mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Does it mean ***traditional*** profession or ***authoritative*** profession? I looked it up in M/W, but I am not sure where it belongs.

> What is unusual about journalism as a profession is its lack of
> independence. In theory, practitioners in the ***classic
> professions***, like medicine or the clergy, contain the means of
> production in their heads and hands, and therefore do not have to work
> for a company or an employer. They can draw their income directly from
> their clients or patients. Because the professionals hold knowledge,
> moreover, their clients are dependent on them. Journalists hold
> knowledge, but it is not theoretical in nature; one might argue that
> the public depends on journalists in the same way that patients depend
> on doctors, but in practice a journalist can serve the public usually
> only by working for a news organization, which can fire her or him at
> will. Journalists’ income depends not on the public, but on the
> employing news organization, which often derives the large majority of
> its revenue from advertisers.

[Journalism](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=-5BdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT48&lpg=PT48&dq=What%20is%20unusual%20about%20journalism%20as%20a%20profession%20is%20its%20lack%20of%20independence.%20In%20theory,%20practitioners%20in%20the%20classic%20professions,%20like%20medicine%20or%20the%20clergy,%20contain%20the%20means%20of%20production%20in%20their%20heads%20and%20hands,&source=bl&ots=w0u2zaWJ3t&sig=ACfU3U14Y3aByoXgiR95qiRmMZoFL3iQfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAx8T4r5f-AhXGZt4KHVA6Do0Q6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=What%20is%20unusual%20about%20journalism%20as%20a%20profession%20is%20its%20lack%20of%20independence.%20In%20theory%2C%20practitioners%20in%20the%20classic%20professions%2C%20like%20medicine%20or%20the%20clergy%2C%20contain%20the%20means%20of%20production%20in%20their%20heads%20and%20hands%2C&f=false)

Comment: The quoted text says 'classic', not 'classical'.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I just mistyped, but the definition relates to classic.

Comment: It means jobs that were traditionally regarded as 'the professions', like the examples they give.

Comment: Where did you find anything to suggest that ***classic***  implies ***authoritative***?

Comment: I found it in Merriam Webster.   classic: 4a  AUTHENTIC, AUTHORITATIVE

Comment: Your text gives you examples.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean traditional profession or authoritative profession?

"authoritative profession" doesn't make much sense here. It means "traditional profession".

A few definitions in dictionary.com:

- traditional or typical
- serving as a standard, model, or guide
- basic; fundamental
- definitive

From wiktionary:

- Traditional; original

As a reader (who is not a professional economist or journalist) the term "classic professions" doesn't strike me as an idiom, but simply two regular English words being used with their normal meanings in a sentence.